# mod_rewrite for seo friendly urls with 5 parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page in the following location: /property/happy_property_urls.php

My goal is to make the happy looking url's look like this: /en/london/apartment/for-rent/ww123/

I have tried various methods but none of them seem to stick and I only get 404 errors.

**EXAMPLE NOT WORKING**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /property/
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ happy_property_urls.php?lang=$1&city=$2&type=$3&status=$4&ref=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I am sadly failing badly.

Can someone give me some pointers please?

Comment: you've got one SINGLE capture group `(.*?)`, and trying to use values from **FIVE** groups (`$1` -> `$5`)?

Comment: Do your URL contain the word /property in it?

Comment: I am also trying RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /property/happy_property_urls.php?lang=$1&city=$2&type=$3&status=$4&ref=$5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in the `.htaccess` in the `root`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ property/happy_property_urls.php?lang=$1&city=$2&type=$3&status=$4&ref=$5 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @CraigEdmonds glad to hear it.